# Analytically solving PDEs on irregular domains in Physics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, mathematical-physics

In many Physics courses you solve PDEs like heat or wave on square, circular, or spherical domains with separation of variables. Are there ways to solve PDEs and Boundary value problems on irregular domains given by some function analytically? For example the wave equation inside a waveguide where the cross sectional shape is given by the intersection between 2 defined curves a parabola and a cubic for example. Another example could be the Schrödinger equation for a particle in a 3D cavity given by the intersection of 2 surfaces. Keep in mind the irregular boundaries are defined by functions.

I know separation of variables wont work but are there other methods for irregular domains given by functions? Would eigenfunction expansions or variational methods work? What I am asking is are there methods to solve Linear PDEs on irregular domains where the boundaries are defined by functions? I know there are numerical methods for PDEs on irregular domains what I want to know is are there Analytical methods approximate or exact for PDEs on irregular domains?

Comment: This isn't really a physics question though and would likely find better answers on [math.se].

Comment: It is because many physics problems involve solving PDEs. Its absolutely relevant to Physics.

Comment: You don't seem to be interested in any physics here, just methods of solving PDEs under certain conditions. Seems to me [math.se] would be a more appropriate venue.

Comment: You can also solve PDE with simple fractal domains analytically (not necessarily defined by an explicit function). Check out the last chapter of Falconer’s *Techniques in Fractal Geomtery*

Comment: As long as the boundary is separable in one of 11 curviliear coordinate sysytems for the Helmholtz equation, then one can proceed analytically.  There are special cases, such as a triangular shaped cross-section of a waveguide, that have analytical solutions.

Comment: What if it isnt separable in any coordinate system are there alternative methods to solve PDEs on irregular domains analytically

Answer (score 0):

From my knowledge, one of the most used tool to deal with irregular domains in such cases is to implement conformal mapping (and therefore reduce the problem to the problem defined in e.g. a circle). You can google 'conformal mappings equations irregular domains' and find some examples of how it is done in particular cases.